# How can one change the primary key using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I want to change the primary key of an entity in database, so that all the relevant foreign key constraints are updated as well./We are using NHibenate as our ORM.

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks.

P.S.

I know the practice of changing the primary key is highly discouraged. My problem is that my primary key is backed by a natural Id of the entity, which may sometimes change. We could, theoretically, utilize a unique primary key, unrelated to the natural key of the entity, but this complicates things too much in other places, so this is not an option.

Comment: I'd like to know how it "complicates things too much in other places" - I've been using surrogate keys (and occasionally natural keys) for *years* and have almost always found that it *simplifies* things.

Comment: Well, using surrogate keys will require that the server either performs extra lookups in the database or maintain a local cache of certain objects. It was too much work until a need to change natural keys has arrived. I guess I would have to switch to surrogate keys and just absorb the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on your question.... nHibernate is just a mapping of your database. It seems that to do what you are suggesting you just need to change your database to whatever you need it to be, redo your mapping files, then modify any queries you have to match the new schema...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. NHibernate will complain if you try to do it.

The only way to do it "from" NHibernate is using `CreateSQLQuery`.